# How to get proper German hyphenation?

Tags: babel, hyphenation, german

Code:

```
\documentclass[paper=3.5cm:5cm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Andere übertragen das am besten den Geschwistern.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Rendered document]

Hyphenation for these standard German words is incorrect. I know that we can
specify hyphenation manually, e.g. `übertra\-gen`, but that makes source code
less readable, and it would be tedious for an entire book.

*How do I tell LaTeX to use proper hyphenation?*

Desired hyphenation is for a German text authored between 1914 and 1918.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `german` package is obsolete. You should instead load

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Example, where `\parbox{0pt}` is used to force TeX to hyphenate as much as possible.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}Andere übertragen das am besten den Geschwistern.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will still get a lot of words wrong, using `\usepackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}` is recommended.

Comment: @KonstantinW I thought it's `\babelprovide[hyphenrules=ngerman-x-latest]{ngerman}`. Any difference between the two?

Comment: @KonstantinW That was OP's point, in fact, they needed the hyphenation rules that were in use 100 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I used...

```
\documentclass[ngerman, a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

...and there were still errors with hyphenation.

What fixed it for me was:

```
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=ngerman-x-latest]{ngerman}
```

Comment: That was OP's point, in fact, they needed the hyphenation rules that were in use 100 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The "ngerman" language variant hyphenates according to the rules introduced by the "Rechtschreibreform" 1996.
The OP wanted

> hyphenation [..] for a German text authored between 1914 and 1918

To use the hyphenation rules valid at this time (de-1901), replace "ngerman" with "german".

Comment: I believe this is covered by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255808)'s answer which uses `german` and not `ngerman`.

Comment: While in the given example the hyphenation is correct, more and better hyphenation for de-1901 can be achieved with the "german-x-latest" patterns from "dehyph-exptl", i.e. a mix of egreg's and themenance's answers --- adding `\babelprovide[hyphenrules=german-x-latest]{german}` to egreg's example.