# Hyphenation for german words wanted

Tags: hyphenation

I am currently working on a german document. While proof-reading I noticed a lot of places where the hyphenation is not correct. My current solution to this problem is to separate the word in question manually, e.g.

```
Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän
```

becomes

```
Don\-au\-dampf\-schiff\-fahrts\-ge\-sell\-schafts\-ka\-pi\-tän.
```

But I have to do this for every occurence using search and replace. Is there another way, like a central dictionary mechanism I have not heard of yet? Maybe with an integration for an editor like Notepad++ or Atom that autosuggests hyphenized words?

I am using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as suggested here: [How to get proper German hyphenation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255806/how-to-get-proper-german-hyphenation)

I am also using `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` but this does not solve the issue.

Comment: Doesn't `\hyphenation{Don-au-dampf-schiff-fahrts-ge-sell-schafts-ka-pi-tän}` work?

Comment: It does. But I was wondering if there is a possibility to generate a user-defined dictionary in one central place. Or even contribute to the dictionary that is used. I guess this would be in the babel package, right?

Comment: If I use the Rechtschreibung *Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän* (with three f's), I get `Do-nau-dampf-schiff-fahrts-ge-sell-schafts-ka-pi-tän`

Comment: @gentlesea Even in standard set of hyphenation rules there are exceptions, added by `\hyphenation` command. See, e.g., `hyphen.tex`.

Comment: I get the correct hyphenation `Do-nau-dampf-schiff-fahrts-ge-sell-schafts-ka-pi-tän` when using ngerman + babel. So you should show a concrete and complete example where hyphenation fails for you.

Comment: Gentlesea: couldn't you just create a file with all the hyphenation commands and input it into your tex file?

Comment: Concrete example is Fernbedienung. Gets Fernbedi-enung in my case. \hyphenation{Fern-be-die-nung} solves this. @riddleculous: This is a good idea, I just created a file hyphenationDictionary.tex which I use with  \input{"CommonSubdocuments/hyphenationDictionary"}.

Answer (score 5):

With an current MiKTeX 2.9 (version `3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400 64-bit)`) I can compile the following MWE without problems with the hyphenation. `Fernbedienung` is hyphenated as it should be ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän. Fernbedienung}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issues, for a lot of German words the hyphenation is still incorrect. You can add the `hyphsubst` package to overcome this shortcoming.

`\usepackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}`

Answer (score 1):

Won't `\hyphenation{Don-au-dampf-schiff-fahrts-ge-sell-schafts-ka-pi-tän}` once at the beginning of the document be sufficient?