# Why no hyphenation of "kön-nen" in German?

Tags: hyphenation

I have a LaTeX document that has a sentence containing the German word "können" (which can be hyphenated perfectly as "kön-nen" IMHO). An ugly paragraph is output, because the word is not hyphenated by default (other Words are, of course).

If I use `kön\-nen` instead, the paragraph looks fine.

The input sentence (incorrectly) is: "Um alle Farben des Eingabefarbraums im Ausgabefarbraum abzubilden zu können,
muß der Eingabefarbraum durch Umrechnung der Farben in den Ausgabefarbraum
eingepaßt werden."

Here is the incorrect output:
[image: Output with no hyphenation (red line added manually)]

And here is the "correct" output (note that Ausgabefarbraum's hyphenation is incorrect):
[image: Output with correct hyphenation of "können"]

The packages being used are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
```

Is it the same problem as in [How to get proper German hyphenation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255806/how-to-get-proper-german-hyphenation)?
For an older version of LaTeX (about 1999) these packages worked.

Comment: Don't use \usepackage{german} but \usepackage[german]{babel}, also load \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} if you want to enable hyphenation in words with Umlauts.

Comment: Well given that the answer to that question says clearly that "the `german` package is obsolete", it seems likely...

Comment: Sorry, but you are told several times in your old questions **not to use the outdated package `german`**! Same for package `a4`! Why do you not follow this advices? Using this old packages can result in such errors you got in your example. So **please, please, please** do not use them any longer!

Comment: You might also want to use the Unicode, with `\usepackage{fontspec}`, instead of `fontenc` and `inputenc`. This allows you to use standard fonts as well.

Comment: @Davislor This is misleading information. You can't use `fontspec` with pdfLaTeX, only with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. So telling someone who's using pdfLaTeX to simply use `fontspec` will cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: @AlanMunn All right: for a new document, my personal recommendation is to compile in LuaLaTeX, not PDFLateX. If that doesn’t work, XeLaTeX. There are not many publishers or professors who still force you to use PDFLaTeX.

Comment: @AlanMunn It’s true that the questioner here seems to be trying to get a twenty-year-old document to compile, and for that, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is the quickest fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with *können* is that a T1-encoded font has to be used. Otherwise, accents such as the *umlaut* are produced with the `\accent` primitive and TeX will not hyphenate words past it.

In the code below I commented `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` because all my editors use UTF-8 (which is the default in LaTeX since some releases).

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[textwidth=5in,lines=54]{geometry} % emulates a4.sty

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Um alle Farben des Eingabefarbraums im Ausgabefarbraum abzubilden zu
können, muß der Eingabefarbraum durch Umrechnung der Farben in den
Ausgabefarbraum eingepaßt werden.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Notes.** The package `german` is obsolete. Use `babel` instead; I left `german` instead of `ngerman` (that's tailored for the *neue Rechtschreibung*).

Also `a4` is deprecated and obsolete. Besides it mysteriously sets the text width to 5 inches, which is quite bizarre.

Anyway, it's very simple to do the same with a modern and maintained package such as `geometry`.

Comment: I added `\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}`, and the result was that "können" still needs manual hyphenation while "Ausgabefarbraum" was hyphenated correctly. If I changed the `OT1` to `T1` (as suggested), everything worked! Still I could need an explanation!

Comment: @U.Windl Doing `\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}` or not is exactly the same.

Comment: No doubts, but maybe you could elaborate a bit more what the magic behind `T1` actually means. Once `OT1` seemed to work.

Comment: OT1 never worked. It builds  Umlauts with the accent command and this prohibits hyphenation.

Comment: @U.Windl TeX will stop hyphenating past an accented letter that's not available in the font as a precomposed character. So no, OT1 has *never* worked for hyphenating *können*, because the umlaut is obtained with the `\accent` primitive (that stops hyphenation).

Comment: I found this document to be useful, helping to understand the issue better: https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf

Comment: @U.Windl OT1 is a seven-bit encoding from the 1980s. For backward compatibility, TeX uses it by default. Because it only has room for 127 characters, it doesn’t come with accents. T1 is a still-obsolete encoding from the ’90s. It’s eight-bit instead of seven-bit and supports western European languages. To use modern fonts and encodings `\usepackage{fontspec}` **instead** of either `fontenc` or `inputenc`.

Comment: @U.Windl I should clarify: LaTeX still uses it as the default *output* encoding. Since 2018, the default *input* encoding has been UTF-8.

Comment: +1. :-) To hyphenate `Ausgabefarbraum` ("output color space") correctly, add the instruction `\hyphenation{aus-gabe-farb-raum}` after loading `babel` in the preamble...