# German hyphenation, latest rules, permanent file name?

Tags: babel, german

I notice that `babel` and `polyglossia` provide for old (1901) and new (1996) german hyphenation, with `german-x-latest` and `ngerman-x-latest` as alternatives to what I assume is the more stable `german` and `ngerman`. Not being a German writer, I searched on this site, and found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255806/how-to-get-proper-german-hyphenation/673417#673417) useful post.

My question: If I specifically request the `-x-latest` files, will those continue to work for the foreseeable future? That is, are the `-x-latest` permanent file names, or will they be removed if and when German becomes more fixed? Or, if they are removed, will LaTeX be automatically directed to the correct files?

Comment: The reform itself has been reformed a few times, and hyphenation patterns are amended from time to time. *-x-latest are not actual files but aliases, defined in language.dat. Obviously not being able to speak for the developers, I don't think that's going to change soon.

Comment: @Ingmar If the `-x-latest` are aliases, that is good. It does not hurt my application, if the hyphenation evolves, as long as I can request a particular name. I still find it hard to believe that `british` and `american` are not `english`, and that `german` uses `\frenchspacing` rather than `\nonfrenchspacing`.